# My timer won't function (I use Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Here's the code:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
```

and

```
private void mainWinForm_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        timer.Start();

    timer.Elapsed += delegate
        {
            int count = 0;

            count++;

            if (count == 1)
            {
                label1.Text = "3 (Get ready!)";
            }

            if (count == 2)
            {
                label1.Text = "2 (To smile! :) )";
            }

            if (count == 3)
            {
                label1.Text = "1 (Cheeese!)";
            }

            if (count == 4)
            {
                label1.Text = "Taken!";
                imgCapture.Image = imgVideo.Image;
            }

            timer.Stop();
        };
}
```

I am pretty new to C# so It's probably a stupid mistake I made? When I press the space button. nothing happens to the label

Comment: Could it be that you set count = 0 every time the event is raised? Therefore the label text will always be "3 ...". Also you are stopping the timer, when the event is raised.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your code will always set the text to "Get ready", because you will always create a variable called `count` with the value `0` when your timer elapses. Try to move the variable outside the delegate, so that it persist. Also take a look at (this debugging technique, it is really helpful in most cases)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging].

Comment: You are stopping the timer in the first iteration! Remove the timer.Stop() or put it in the if (count == 4) statement. And you have to make count a class-variable.

Comment: I don't know, but I would try moving the event subscription above starting the timer, just in case Timer has some weird check that is has an elapsed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that you are using a threaded Timer. Therefore the elapsed delegate will be called on a different thread. And crossthread calls to the UI are not allowed. Have you disabled Exceptions in the debugger? Your code should throw an Exception when you assign something to label1.Text in the elapsed event.

After creating the Timer set the SynchronizingObject property to a class that belongs to the UI thread (your form would be a perfect fit). That will synchronize the Elapsed event into the main thread and the UI can be manipulated.

```
   var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
   timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
   timer.AutoReset = true; // the event will be fired just once no need to stop the timer. 
   timer.Elapsed += delegate
   {
      // your code
   }
```

Comment: Error 2 'System.Timers.Timer' does not contain a definition for 'SynchronizationObject' and no extension method 'SynchronizationObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Timers.Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Corrected the code i just misspelled the property. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx

Answer (score 2):

When your timer fires it executes your delegate. Which looks like this:

```
{
    int count = 0;
    count++;

    if (count == 1)
    {
       label1.Text = "3 (Get ready!)";
    }

    // cases for other values of count removed   

    timer.Stop();
}
```

Now, each time the delegate runs it creates a new local variable and initialises it to `0`. So you can only ever enter the `count == 1` branch. And when the delegate completes, it disables the timer. So you should see the label change to `"3 (Get ready!)"` and then nothing more happen. That's what the code says.

What you intended to do was have different behaviour each time the delegate fires. What you need to happen is for the delegate to run multiple times, and perform different actions each time it runs. In order for that to happen there needs to be a mechanism for state to be remembered between separate executions of your delegate.

You can achieve that like so:

1. Move the `count` variable outside the delegate. It should be a private field of your form class. Or perhaps a local variable in the key down handler.
2. Initialise `count` to `0` before your start the timer.
3. In your delegate, increment `count`, and then set the label text accordingly.
4. If you have detected that no more updates need to be made to the label, then stop the timer.

Your code might look like this:

```
private void mainWinForm_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
        int count = 0; // NOTE: outside the delegate
        timer.Elapsed += delegate
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                label1.Text = "3 (Get ready!)";
            }
            if (count == 2)
            {
                label1.Text = "2 (To smile! :) )";
            }
            if (count == 3)
            {
                label1.Text = "1 (Cheeese!)";
            }
            if (count == 4)
            {
                label1.Text = "Taken!";
                imgCapture.Image = imgVideo.Image;
                timer.Stop();
            }
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

One problem with this is that it looks like you will be re-using the same timer instance. So the second time you subscribe to `Elapsed`, you will add a second instance of the delegate. I'd be inclined to make the timer be a local variable of the key down event handler.

So then the code would look like this:

```
private void mainWinForm_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
        int count = 0; // NOTE: outside the delegate
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += delegate
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                label1.Text = "3 (Get ready!)";
            }
            if (count == 2)
            {
                label1.Text = "2 (To smile! :) )";
            }
            if (count == 3)
            {
                label1.Text = "1 (Cheeese!)";
            }
            if (count == 4)
            {
                label1.Text = "Taken!";
                imgCapture.Image = imgVideo.Image;
                timer.Stop();
            }
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I understand, but the label still won't change using your code.

Comment: Use the debugger. Dors the timer even fire?

Comment: I've tried the code for even a button click, and there's no joy, how can I tell if it has fired?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set the Elapsed event delegate before starting the timer

```
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
  {
        int count = 0;
        timer.Elapsed += delegate
        {
          count++;
          ....
        }
        timer.Start();

 }
```

Also include the code inside the if block and move the declaration of the variable count outside the delegate code. Keeping the declaration inside the event code will reset it to zero every time the Elapsed event fires

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here. I think he mistakenly initializes a `count` variable everytime his timer elapses.

Comment: Yes @ChrisK that's true, but, at least the label "3 (Get ready!)" should be set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `KeyPreview` property of your form  to `True` to handle Events on the Windows Form.